# How to save simple_form_for field in a différent controller ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, simple-form-for

Rails version 5.1.4

Hello,

I can't save the field value **immo_type** of my simple_form_for to my controller **Pages**

```
#app\controllers\pages_controller.rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, only: [:home]

  def home
    @purchase = Purchase.new
    @immo_type = params[:immo_type]

  end
end
```

The view :

```
#app\views\pages\home.html.erb    
<%= simple_form_for @purchase, url: purchases_path(@purchase), :method => :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :address %>
  <%= f.input :immo_type %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Search" %>
```

The model :

```
#app\models\purchase.rb
class Purchase < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :users, :through => :searches
end
```

Sorry i'm new on ruby on rails !!!

I try to put `<%= debug params %>`or make "raise" in my Pages controller. I've this message

> --- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess controller: pages
>   action: home permitted: false

Could you help me please ?

Comment: there should be a create action to save form data

Comment: Is there a relationship between Purchase and Immo_Type?

Comment: immo_type belongs to purchase Tab as address

Answer (score 0):

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, only: [:home]

  def create
      purchase=Purchase.new(purchase_params)
      if purchase.save
       flash[:notice] = "purchase saved successfully."
       redirect_to root_path
      else
       flash[:error] = purchase.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
       redirect_to :back
      end
    end

    private
    def purchase_params
      params.require(:purchase).permit(:address,immo_type)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So, first i need to work with a search controller with the home and index views

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

    def home
        @searches = params[:immo_type]
    end

    def index
        @purchases = Purchase.search_by_immo_type_and_address("#{params[:purchase][:immo_type]}")
    end
end
```

This is my purchase model with Pg_Search gem

```
class Purchase < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :users, :through => :searches

    include PgSearch
    pg_search_scope :search_by_immo_type_and_address, against: [:immo_type]
end
```

And the view with simple_form_for

```
<%= simple_form_for :purchase, url: searches_url, method: :get do |f| %>
            <%= f.input :address %> 
            <%= f.input :immo_type %>
            <%= f.button :submit, "Rechercher"%>
<% end %>
```

I hope it can help you